# How to calculate balance amount in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

[image: calculate stock movement]

I want to calculate weight by product and by date.Now I use running total field . But my balance is not ok .How can I solve it?

Comment: how this 8, 204, 32 comes, how to calculate? where is product code? I think A1,A2.... If yes, then why date comes at below. What is your grouping id?

Comment: @ Ajay2707 , thank for reply , I want to get A1 balance weight for 11/9/2014 ( 10 - 2  = 8) and then for 13/9/2014 balance weight (8-3=5) and then for 15/09/2014 (5+111-0 = 116) .......something like that.grouping by product code. Product code is (A1,A2..) , you right.

Comment: how you calculate now. so I will assist you. Also what is your grouping id.

Comment: @Ajay2707 , you means grouping id is crystal report group field? Now I group by product code and want to show day by day transaction.

Comment: I dont think you really need a running total. You will need to group by Product Code and then by Date and then create a formula for Balance Weight in the lines of {BalanceWeight - OutWeight}